# PHP full text search - how to match the exact search

Tags: php, mysql

I tried searching for this answer but still no luck. I'm no expert on PHP so please help me find an answer for this:

I need to match the exact search, if I have this database:

orange

yellow blue

yellow orange

red yellow

The current results for the search "yellow orange" are all the entries that have yellow in it plus the ones that have orange (yellow orange, yellow blue, red yellow and orange).

But I want it finding only the exact match: yellow orange.

How can I do that?

`if($_GET["txtKeyword"] != "") {`

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE  MATCH (example1, example2, example3, example4)     
   AGAINST (SUBSTRING_INDEX('%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%', ' ', 1) IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND public = 'Sim' ";
```

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). An interface which supports placeholders for SQL data like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). `$_GET` and `$_POST` data **NEVER** goes directly in a query.

Comment: Did you try something like this: `$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE column = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['txtKeyword']);`

Comment: That won't work since I need to match several columns :/